# 256 bit image mask for xterm-256

Tags: c++, ncurses

I am using `ncurses` with `c++` on a `xterm-256` display and I would like to print my text in shades of red, but I'm having trouble finding a simple way to do this.

Using [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) chart I can see that `0x009` is red and that `0x255` - `0x232` will be various shades of black. How can I go about using this information to form a mast for my colors?

I would basically like to form a map such that `10` means white and `20` means red, such that `15` would be pink and so on. I would then create color pairs with

```
init_pair(10, ???, COLOR_BLACK);
init_pair(11, ???, COLOR_BLACK);
...
init_pair(20, ???, COLOR_BLACK);
```

so that I could use these colors later to shade from white to red.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what assumptions you want to make.  The layout of the xterm 256color feature is a given, with three parts:

1. colors 0-15 are ANSI colors and bright versions of those.
2. colors 16-231 are a 6x6x6 color cube
3. colors 232-255 are a grayscale ramp, intentionally leaving out black and white

See for example [256color.pl](https://gist.github.com/hSATAC/1095100) (widely copied from xterm sources).  The numbers make more sense than [the chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) when you see the picture:

[image]

You could simply refer to those color numbers in `init_pair`.  Bright red as you have noticed is 9 (`COLOR_RED` + 8).

On the other hand, the color palette can be modified.  You could use [`init_color`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_color.3x.html) (giving your own red/green/blue triple) to define a color by number, and use *that* in `init_pair`.